# How can I change project application when released from Lollipop to Jelly Bean?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I had changed build.gradle from `minSdkVersion 19` to be `minSdkVersion 10`, but when  I try to install it on my emulator running android Kitkat, its not working and the app just show the application has stopped.. I tried installing it on Lollipop where its working as intended. what should I do?

here's my code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
}
```

Comment: When the application stops you get also an error message.

Comment: in my emulator Android Lollipop not show any error message...

Comment: You don't need multidex for your project. Try disabling it with `multiDexEnabled false`. And minimum SDK version is 14 for support library 26, so you can't use  `minSdkVersion 10`

Comment: i have do what you says, but still no effected on my project the app just show the application has stopped when i install on Android Kitkat

Comment: what is the error log? Probably you're using a method specific for api > 19.

Comment: Android Studio not show any error